# Can a continuous real valued function, differentiable everywhere but $x_0$, be expressed as $g(x)+h(x)|x-x_0|$ for some differentiable $g$ and $h$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that f is differentiable on both intervals $(-\infty, x_0]$ and $[x_0, +\infty)$. Prove or disprove that there exist two functions $g, h : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ differentiable everywhere such that

$$
f(x) = g(x) + h(x)|x - x_0|\ \ \forall x \in \mathbb R.
$$

This feels like it characterizes every non-differentiable point of a continuous function in terms of absolute values but I couldn't come up with a function to disprove nor I was able to construct $g$ and $h$.

Help and directions appreciated.

Comment: Note that there might be non-differentiable points where the one-sided limits do not exist, like in $\sqrt{|x|}$, or where the non-differentiable points accumulate somewhere. In both cases you won't have differentiability on $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0]$ and $[x_0,x_0+\varepsilon)$, so it certainly doesn't characterize *every* non-differentiable point of a continuous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint (to be read after copper.hat hint).

Let us consider the following two differentiable extensions of $f$:
$$F_+(x) = \begin{cases} f(x), & x \ge x_0, \\
f(x_0)+f'_+(x_0)(x-x_0), & x \le x_0, \end{cases}$$
and 
$$F_-(x) = \begin{cases} f(x), & x \le x_0, \\
f(x_0)+f'_-(x_0)(x-x_0), & x \ge x_0. \end{cases}$$
Then $F:=F_+ + F_-$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and
$$F(x)-f(x)=f(x_0)+\begin{cases} 
f'_+(x_0)(x-x_0), & x \le x_0,  \\
f'_-(x_0)(x-x_0), & x \ge x_0, \end{cases}$$
that is
$$F(x)-f(x)=f(x_0)+f'_+(x_0)\cdot \frac{x-x_0 -|x-x_0|}{2}
+f'_-(x_0)\cdot \frac{x-x_0 +|x-x_0|}{2}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint:

Suppose $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} ax, & x < 0 \\
bx, & x \ge 0 \end{cases}$, note that we can write
$\phi(x) = {b-a \over 2} |x| + {a+b \over 2} x$.

Comment: This is a "shining"  hint!! (+1)

Comment: copper.hat. As always, very nice! +)